# What is the derivative of $\tan^{-1}(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have seen the derivative of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ set equal to both $\sec^{-2}(x)$ and $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

I can't find corroborating sources for either claim, so I'm asking here if either of these are true.

Comment: Let $u= arctan x$ then take tan for both sides $\tan u = x$ use implicit differential derivative $ u’ sec^2 u = 1$ hence

Answer (score 4):

This stems from the fact that many sources use the conflicting definitions that
$$\tan^{-1}{(x)}=\arctan{(x)}$$
But one may also interpret this as
$$\tan^{-1}{(x)}=\frac1{\tan{(x)}}$$
Both of these functions have different derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to: what do you mean by $\tan^{-1}(x)$. I think most people think of it as the inverse tangent function, i.e. $\arctan(x)$, but some think of it as $\frac{1}{\tan(x)}$. The derivative of the former is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, and the derivative of $\tan(x)$ is $\sec^2(x)$.

Comment: The derivative of $\frac{1}{\tan{(x)}}=\cot{(x)}$ is $-\csc^2{(x)}$

Comment: Yeah I meant $\tan(x)$, so I updated it.

Comment: Thank you. This answer was easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If $y=\arctan x$ then $x=\tan y$ so $\frac{dx}{dy}=\sec^2y=1+x^2$. Therefore, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is $\sec^{-2}y$ (note it's $y$, not $x$; also, we'd usually write $\cos^2 y$) or $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

On the other hand, if $y=(\tan x)^{-1}$ then $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\tan^{-2}x\sec^2 x=-\csc^2 x=-(1+y^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

If by $\tan^{-1}$ you mean the inverse function of the *restriction* of $\tan$ to the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, i.e. the function $\arctan$, you can apply the general formula for the derivative of an inverse function:
$$(\arctan)'(x)=\frac 1{(\tan)'(\arctan x)}==\frac 1{1+\tan^2(\arctan x)}=\frac 1{1+x^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $\tan(\arctan(x)) = x$, and we can differentiate implicitly:

$$\tan'(\arctan(x))\arctan'(x) = 1$$

Rearranging:

$$\arctan'(x) = 1/\sec^2(\arctan(x))$$

See that $\sec(\arctan(x)) = \sqrt{1 + x^2}$ from the right triangle:

$\qquad \qquad \qquad$ [image]

So $\displaystyle \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \arctan(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}$.

---

**Note**: This approach can be applied to find the derivative of *any* inverse function, assuming you know the derivative of the function itself. 
 To wit:

Suppose $g(x) = f^{-1}(x)$.  Then:

\begin{align}
&f(g(x)) = x \\[1em]
&f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) = 1 \qquad \quad \text{(Differentiating implicitly)} \\[1em]
&g'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(g(x))}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of the inverse tangent function ($f(x)=\tan^{-1}{x}$), also commonly known as the arctangent function ($f(x)=\arctan{x}$), is: $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}.$$

Period. It's definitely not $\sec^{-2}{x}$. That's just pure nonsense. In fact, if you are thinking of $\tan^{-1}{x}$ as the reciprocal of the tangent function, then the derivative of $\frac{1}{\tan{x}}$ would actually be $-\csc^2{x}$:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{\tan{x}}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\bigg[(\tan{x})^{-1}\bigg]=-1\cdot\left(\tan{x}\right)^{-1-1}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\tan{x}\right)=\\
-\frac{1}{\tan^2{x}}\cdot\sec^2{x}=-\frac{1}{\frac{\sin^2{x}}{\cos^2{x}}}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos^2{x}}=-\frac{1}{\sin^2{x}}=-\csc^2{x}.
$$