# Is $\tan^{-1}x$ or $\frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{2}$ the integral of $\frac{1}{1+x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

$\displaystyle \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \tan^{-1}x = \frac{1}{1+x}$

$\displaystyle \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{2} = \frac{1}{1+x}$

So couldn't $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{1+x} \ \text{d}x$ be either of those two functions? Which is it?

Comment: both derivatives are incorrect. $(\arctan x)'=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $\left(\frac{1}{2}(\ln(1+x^2))\right)'=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: @AnuragA Jesus I'm tired, thanks haha

Comment: Were your formulas correct, we would have $$\tan^{-1}(x)=\frac12\ln(x^2+1)+C,$$ which would be a revolution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry, what do you mean? Is that some how applicable to solids/surfaces of revolution?

Comment: @JamesRonald: haha, I mean a revolution in mathematics...

Comment: $$\tan ^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{2} i \log \left(\frac{1-i x}{1+i x}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler: it's merely $\ln(1 + x)$—up to a constant of integration of course.  Setting $u = 1 \!+\! x$, the integral becomes:

$$\int \frac{1}{1+x} \ \text{d}x \ = \ \int \frac{1}{u} \ \text{d}u \ = \ \ln(u) + c \ = \ \ln(1+x) + c$$

Indeed, you can check that $\displaystyle \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \Big( \ln( 1+ x) + c \Big) = \frac{1}{1+x}$.

---

You can read about how to compute the derivative of the inverse tangent function [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3162359/what-is-the-derivative-of-tan-1x/3162401#3162401), and as for $\displaystyle \frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{2}$, notice that the chain rule will force an $x^2$ term in the denominator of its derivative.

Answer (score 0):

You are not so far:

$$\begin{align}\int\frac{dx}{1+ix}&=\frac{\ln(1+ix)}i+C\\&=\color{blue}{\arctan x}-i\color{green}{\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}2}+C.\end{align}$$